# hide/show div depending on option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am very confused why is this it doesn't show my div. This is just a simple idea, i have two divs which is :

```
<div id="custom-report">
</div>

<div id="daily-report">
</div>
```

now, i have a select which select when i want to hide or show them:

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectedrep">
    <option value="0">--- SELECT OPTION ---</option>
    <option value="1">Daily</option>
    <option value="2">Custom</option>
</select>
```

and i am doing my javascript like this:

```
$('#selectedrep').change(function(){
    var selectedReport = $(this).val();
    if(selectedReport == 1) {
      document.getElementById('daily-report').style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('custom-report').style.display = '';
      alert("daily");
    }
    if(selectedReport == 2) {
      document.getElementById('custom-report').style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('daily-report').style.display = '';
      alert('custom');
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById('custom-report').style.display = "none"; 
      document.getElementById('daily-report').style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

and also first, i will hide them all with my css with this:

```
#custom-report {
    display: none;
}
#daily-report {
    display: none;
}
```

why is it, when i go navigate to daily, it will show, and just vanished. and if i go navigate for custom, it will show my div correctly.

Comment: just change `if` on the second condition to `else if` it will work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second condition, you should have `else if` instead of `if`

`Else` condition is only considered when second `if` condition fails, not every time. ***`if....else if...else`*** flow would solve this problem.

```js
$('#selectedrep').change(function() {
  var selectedReport = $(this).val();
  if (selectedReport == 1) {
    document.getElementById('daily-report').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('custom-report').style.display = '';
  } else if (selectedReport == 2) {
    document.getElementById('custom-report').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('daily-report').style.display = '';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('custom-report').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('daily-report').style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
#custom-report {
  display: none;
}

#daily-report {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="custom-report">
  CUSTOM
</div>

<div id="daily-report">
  DAILY
</div>

<select class="form-control" id="selectedrep">
    <option value="0">--- SELECT OPTION ---</option>
    <option value="1">Daily</option>
    <option value="2">Custom</option>
</select>
```

***Simplified code -***

```js
$('#selectedrep').change(function() {
  var selectedReport = this.value;
  document.getElementById('custom-report').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('daily-report').style.display = "none";
  if (selectedReport == 1) {
    document.getElementById('daily-report').style.display = "block";
  } else if (selectedReport == 2) {
    document.getElementById('custom-report').style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```css
#custom-report {
  display: none;
}

#daily-report {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="custom-report">
  CUSTOM
</div>

<div id="daily-report">
  DAILY
</div>

<select class="form-control" id="selectedrep">
    <option value="0">--- SELECT OPTION ---</option>
    <option value="1">Daily</option>
    <option value="2">Custom</option>
</select>
```

***Using jQuery(No need to have `css`) -***

```js
$('#selectedrep').change(function() {
  var selectedReport = this.value;
  var custom = $('#custom-report');
  var daily = $('#daily-report');
  custom.add(daily).hide()
  if (selectedReport == 1) {
    daily.show();
  } else if (selectedReport == 2) {
    custom.show();
  }
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="custom-report">
  CUSTOM
</div>

<div id="daily-report">
  DAILY
</div>

<select class="form-control" id="selectedrep">
    <option value="0">--- SELECT OPTION ---</option>
    <option value="1">Daily</option>
    <option value="2">Custom</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have done mistake in `if else`. In your second condition you have to use `if else` instead of only `if`. Please follow below code::

```js
$('#selectedrep').change(function(){
    var selectedReport = $(this).val();
    if(selectedReport == 1) {
      document.getElementById('daily-report').style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('custom-report').style.display = '';
      alert("daily");
    }
    else if(selectedReport == 2) {
      document.getElementById('custom-report').style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('daily-report').style.display = '';
      alert('custom');
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById('custom-report').style.display = "none"; 
      document.getElementById('daily-report').style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

```css
#custom-report {
    display: none;
}
#daily-report {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="custom-report">
Custom Report
</div>

<div id="daily-report">
Daily Report
</div>
<select class="form-control" id="selectedrep">
    <option value="0">--- SELECT OPTION ---</option>
    <option value="1">Daily</option>
    <option value="2">Custom</option>
</select>
```

Also just one thing As you are using **jQuery** `onchange` event you can use **jQuery** for `hide` and `show`. Please follow working jsfiddle link:: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/4su082gq/)

Answer (score 1):

Why cant you add "else" infront of IF statement, this may be your problem.

```
$('#selectedrep').change(function(){
    var selectedReport = $(this).val();
    if(selectedReport == 1) {
      document.getElementById('custom-report').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('daily-report').style.display = "block";
      alert("daily");
}
else if(selectedReport == 2) {  
     document.getElementById('daily-report').style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById('custom-report').style.display = "block";
     alert('custom');
}
else {
     document.getElementById('custom-report').style.display = "none"; 
     document.getElementById('daily-report').style.display = "none";
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second condition, you should have `else if` instead of `if`

Complete jQuery solution based on the fact you have `$('#selectedrep').change()` as your function.

```
$('#selectedrep').change(function() {
  var selectedReport = $(this).val();
  if (selectedReport == 1) {
    $('#daily-report').show();
    $('#custom-report').hide();
  } else if (selectedReport == 2) {
    $('#custom-report').show();
    $('#daily-report').hide();
  } else {
    $('#custom-report').hide();
    $('#daily-report').hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#selectdrep").on("click",function(){
    var selectedvalue = $(this).val();
    if(selectedvalue == "1"){
        document.getElementById("custom-report").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("daily-report").style.display = "none";
    }else if(selectedvalue == "2"){
        document.getElementById("daily-report").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("custom-report").style.display = "none";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("custom-report").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("daily-report").style.display = "none";
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could get rid of the if..else altogether:

```
$("#selectdrep").on("click",function(){
    var selectedvalue = $(this).val();
    document.getElementById("custom-report").style.display = selectvalue == 1 ? "block" : "none";
    document.getElementById("daily-report").style.display = selectvalue == 2 ? "block" : "none";
})
```